# Write data from a variable to a dictionary

Tags: python, json, file, dictionary

I am trying to create a file and write data from a variable to that new file using JSON. Currently, I have a variable called open_diction which is a large dictionary in a file that contains other data. So I am trying to create a new file called open_diction_saved.json and write the data from open_diction to that new file. Currently I am getting the error TypeError:  is not JSON serializable

```
f = open ("open_diction_saved.json","w")
json.dumps(f)
f.write(open_diction)
f.close()
```

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're trying to serialise a writable file object. If your intention is to overwrite `open_diction_saved.json`, then the following code would be what you're looking for.

```
f = open("open_diction_saved.json", 'w')

f.write(json.dumps(open_diction)) #serialise open_diction obj, then write to file
f.close()
```

Comment: Great! That worked thanks for your help and the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

You need to place json.dumps() inside the write() method:

```
import json

open_diction = {'a':1, 'b':2}

with open("open_diction_saved.json", "w") as f:

    f.write(json.dumps(open_diction))
```